# RGA (CRAN) - "get_accounts" gives wrong accounts

Tags: r, google-analytics

> Note it says: RGA package from CRAN. Which is different from "rga"
>   package from Github. Nevertheless, i have the same problem with both
>   packages. But for the question let's stick just to RGA from CRAN.

**The questions is updated and edited, because the first aid was not enough. I still have the problems with the accounts.

I work with 2 emails for accesing Google Analtics. Each one has access to diffent accounts within Google Analytics. I use email A at my house, and email B at work.

Now, im using RGA (from CRAN) within R, and at my house i need to access the Google Analytics accounts from the Email B (work email, that has access to specific Google Analytics accounts).

The problem is that when using this code:

For Account 1: Email A (home email):

```
client.id1 <- "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

client.secret1 <- "bbbbbbbbbbbbbb"


ga_token1 <- authorize(client.id1, client.secret1, cache = TRUE, verbose =    getOption("rga.verbose", FALSE))

get_accounts(start.index = NULL, max.results = NULL, ga_token1, verbose = getOption("rga.verbose", FALSE))
```

For Account 2: Email B (work email):

```
client.id2 <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

client.secret2 <- "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"


ga_token2 <- authorize(client.id2, client.secret2, cache = TRUE, verbose =   getOption("rga.verbose", FALSE))


get_accounts(start.index = NULL, max.results = NULL, ga_token2, verbose =    getOption("rga.verbose", FALSE))
```

What ever, i use at my Home computer,  i get the same accounts fro both my Home Gmail accounts for GA, and my Work Gmail account for GA.

Is there any step that i'm missing?

I want to get the accounts for email B, but no matter what i just get the accounts related with email A.

I've delated all my Google Analytics API projects (from A and B), and recreated the API for Email B. But no matter what, i just get the accounts for email A.

**My Google Api project was created with B (the email with the access to the desire account). But i just see  accounts related to A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears because tokens stored in the same cache file (`.ga-token.rds` by default), i.e. second token replaced first. When tokens are used it read into cache file.

To Solve this issue you should set `cache = FALSE` or define specific cache path for each token. Examples below:

First, disabling cache:

```
work_token <- authorize(client.id1, client.secret1, cache = FALSE)
home_token <- authorize(client.id2, client.secret2, cache = FALSE)
```

Second, different cache paths:

```
work_token <- authorize(client.id1, client.secret1, cache = "work.token")
home_token <- authorize(client.id2, client.secret2, cache = "home.token")
```

To check it:

```
list_profiles(token = work_token)
list_profiles(token = home_token)
```

Comment: thats right. Now i use:     `work_token <- authorize(client.id1,client.secret1, cache = F)`. With this i'm asked to enter my email and password everytime. This is what i needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create two different tokens which will have the authorization for the email you authenticate via the Google login page. Its also a lot easier to get data via the method described in the readme (?rga.open), but for your examples:

```
##authenticate with first email
ga_token1 <- authorize(client.id, client.secret, cache = TRUE, verbose = getOption("rga.verbose", FALSE))
##authenticate with second email
ga_token2 <- authorize(client.id, client.secret, cache = TRUE, verbose = getOption("rga.verbose", FALSE))
```

Then to get accounts:

```
get_accounts(start.index = NULL, max.results = NULL, ga_token1, verbose = getOption("rga.verbose", FALSE))
get_accounts(start.index = NULL, max.results = NULL, ga_token2, verbose = getOption("rga.verbose", FALSE))
```

But I would do it this way:

```
## authenticate under first email
rga.open(instance = "ga1")
## authenticate under second email
rga.open(instance = "ga2")
```

Then to call data such as profiles:

```
profiles1 <- ga1$getProfiles()
profiles2 <- ga2$getProfiles()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the answer. How ever, this token only shows one propierty, and i have 3 with this. The other token shows all the propierties associated. What could be happening? My code: 

`ga_token1 <- authorize(client.id1, client.secret1, cache = TRUE, verbose = getOption("rga.verbose", FALSE)) profilesMGo <- get_accounts(start.index = NULL, max.results = NULL, ga_token1, verbose = getOption("rga.verbose", FALSE)) profilesMGo   ### to print profiles`

Comment: Perhaps that account doesn't have access? In all things GA API I would suggest using the Query Explorer first to get an idea of what is happening: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/ - then you can at least eliminate if its the library or the GA setup you have.

Comment: Thanks, as you see, i was calling "accounts". Instead i had in mind  profiles. "get_profiles()" did the trick. Thanks again, man.

Comment: i thought it was the answer, but not. I just keep having problems with this. Thanks anyway. As you see, now i've created two instances, but with the same results.

Comment: Ahh, confusing.  You are best asking here then: https://bitbucket.org/unikum/rga/issues  - or use rga instead :)